# React Native: trigger event when screen popped off StackNavigator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-native-navigation

I have a StackNavigator in my React Native app, that contains two screens, `Screen1` and `Screen2`. `Screen1` contains a list of items, and when you click one of these items, the StackNavigator pushes `Screen2` onto the stack, displaying information about the item clicked on `Screen1`. On `Screen2` you can click a button to delete the item from the list in `Screen1` (the list is saved in the Redux store). If I refresh the app and navigate to `Screen1`, the deleted item is gone, but what I want to do is have `Screen1` check the Redux store and refresh the list whenever `Screen2` is popped from the stack. I don't think I can use `componentDidMount` or `componentDidUpdate` because neither of these gets triggered when a screen is simply navigated to in a StackNavigator.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the `Redux` will update then you can try `componentWillRecieveProps` method.
For example:

```js
// screen1
state ={ 
  list = [1,2,3]
};

componentWillRecieveProps(nextProps){
     this.setState({list: nextProps.list})
}
```